# Laravel - Llamada api desde blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, api, laravel-6

Tengo este controlador que recibe los datos por `request` y genera un registro en la `BD`, este método si lo llamo desde postman por `post`, me funciona.

**Ruta**

```
Route::post('/user-cars/create', 'Api\UserCarController@create')
->middleware('auth:api')
->name('api.user-cars.create');
```

**Método**

```
 /**
 * @param Request $request
 * @return JsonResponse
 */
public function create(Request $request): JsonResponse
{

    $input = $request->all();

    $validator = Validator::make($input, [
        'name' => 'string',
        'model_id' => 'integer',
        'fuelType' => 'integer',
        'transmission' => 'integer',
        'yearFabrication' => 'integer',
        'potency' => 'integer',

    ]);

    if($validator->fails()){
        return $this->jsonValidatorFailedResponse($validator->errors());
    }

    $car = UserCar::create($input);

    return response()->json($car);
}
```

El problema lo tengo cuando intento hacer un `POST` desde un `template` en blade, de esta forma siempre recibo un 500... En cambio si hago la llamada por postman no.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    $('#btnCreateCar').click(function () {

        var url_route = '{{ route('api.user-cars.create') }}';

        var brand =  $("select[name=brand]").val();
        var model_id =  $("select[name=model]").val();
        var fuelType =  $("select[name=fuelType]").val();
        var transmission =  $("select[name=transmission]").val();
        var yearFabrication =  $("input[name=yearFabrication]").val();
        var potency =  $("input[name=potency]").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: url_route,
            data: {
                brand: brand,
                model_id : model_id,
                fuelType : fuelType,
                transmission : transmission,
                yearFabrication : yearFabrication,
                potency : potency,
            },

            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            },
            error:function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: El código 500 es un error del server, si tuviese un error el request o la autenticación te arrojaria un código diferente, revisa tus archivos log para encontrar el error y puedes actualizar tu pregunta con lo que encuentres.

Comment: Debes adjuntar una captura de lo que dice tu error 500

Comment: a través de su `config/app.php` establezca `'debug'=>env('APP_DEBUG', false)`, a `true`.